# Tangent at a point C1(other than Origin(0,0)) on the curve y=x³ meets.........

Tags: calculus, geometry, tangent-line

> Tangent at a point $C_{1}$ (other than Origin $(0,0)$) on the curve $y=x^3$ meets the curve again at $C_{2}$. The tangent at $C_{2 }$ meets the curve at $C_{3}$ and so on. The abscissae of $C_{1},C_{2},C_{3},.......,{C}_{n}$  form a Geometric Progression .
>
> Find the ratio of the area of the triangles $C_{1}C_{2}C_{3}$ and $C_{2}C_{3}C_{4.}$

Help me visualise this problem

Comment: Please rewrite the posted question using mathjax, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference, and show the own effort to solve the problem, and provide also more support for the question. Please do not use abbreviations like GP (possibly a geometrical progression), the potential answers will type more, so just get a fair share of the work. The question is only a "visualization" issue? Please make this clear.

Comment: I am new here and don't really know all the syntaxes of mathjax Learning with every question

Answer (score 0):

Select a suitable point $C_1$ and draw $T_1$, the tangent at it. Repeat the process.

[image]

Since the bases of the two triangles in question are the same $C_2C_3$, the required ratio is equal to $C_1Q : C_4P$ as shown.

Good luck.